# Fast, robust online note taking tool

Tags: note-taking

Many times I like to store my notes on an online service so I can access them from everywhere or add new notes to them

I like it to be

- secure
- fast loading
- few clicks
- robust
- free, small ad is ok
- just for myself, but it is OK if there are sharing features

NOT needed: mobile app, desktop app, full-text search

Comment: Only as a web site, no mobile/desktop apps needed? Free? Advertisement OK? Do you need full-text search? Do you need any kind of sharing, or only for yourself, nothing shared/public?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul a website, no mibile, no desktop app, free, small ad is ok, no full-text search, more for myself, sharking is ok

Comment: @Ahmad: Would you consider self-hosting it (e.g., on a cheap shared webhosting account), too?

Comment: Something like a personal wiki would work for you if it requires a login?

Comment: @unor I prefer it as another website service, something like google docs. it needs to be permanent. login is OK, but if there is another simple personalizing method is also ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Google Keep:

[image]

- It's fast
- It's free
- Easy to use
- Has mobile apps

Here is a review from [LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/not-just-another-notes-app-why-you-should-use-google-k-509256637)

Answer (score 0):

Ever heard of [Kanbanize](http://kanbanize.com/)?
It's actually a Kanban tool, but also work very well for taking notes.
There is a free version of it, I don't know if the performance is very good because I only use the proversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Zippyjot.com](https://www.zippyjot.com). It is a free online notepad that is fast, very easy to use and does not require a login. You can edit/delete your notes. Search and sort notes by date and title. There's also an auto save feature which will save your notes as you type

Answer (score 0):

I use [simplenote](https://app.simplenote.com/)

It syncs with its [apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.automattic.simplenote&hl=en)

Been using it for 2 years.

There are also many userstyles for the website version if you want to change it into dark version.